# slack not providing original message on interaction

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am responding to an incoming Slack slash command with this JSON (not a POST after receipt):

```
{
  "text": "Testing some interactions!",
  "attachments": [{
    "callback_id": "testing_interactions",
    "attachment_type": "default",
    "actions": [{
      "name": "action",
      "text": "Click Me",
      "value": "clicked",
      "style": "primary",
      "type": "button"
    }]
  }]
}
```

That gives me a nice, pretty, green button to click on and everything seems just fine for the most part; however, according to [the Slack documentation for Interactive Messages](https://api.slack.com/interactive-messages#checking_the_action_type), I should be getting an `original_message` property in the interaction payload.

This does not occur and I only get a sample POST with a payload like this:

```
{
  "type": "interactive_message",
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "action",
      "type": "button",
      "value": "clicked"
    }
  ],
  "callback_id": "testing_interactions",
  "team": {
    "id": "TEAMID",
    "domain": "mydomain"
  },
  "channel": {
    "id": "CHANNELID",
    "name": "directmessage"
  },
  "user": {
    "id": "USERID",
    "name": "me"
  },
  "action_ts": "123456",
  "message_ts": "123456",
  "attachment_id": "1",
  "token": "my_token",
  "is_app_unfurl": false,
  "response_url": "https://hooks.slack.com/actions/...",
  "trigger_id": "some.id"
}
```

I was hoping to be able to the `original_message` property to be able to provide an approve/cancel operation in my target implementation but am unable to.

So two questions:

- What am I missing to get the `original_message` posted back to me on interaction?
- It seems wrong, but is there a need to persist the original data in order to easily recreate a message?

Comment: Is your interactive message ephemeral by any chance? From the docs: `The original_message is not provided for ephemeral messages.`

Comment: D'OH!   RTFM.  That's it.  I must have completely glanced over that in the doc.  If you leave that as the answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad I could help you out here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your interactive message ephemeral by any chance? [From the docs](https://api.slack.com/interactive-messages#checking_the_action_type): `The original_message is not provided for ephemeral messages.`